# How to prevent consumer commit offset when it auto-commit

Tags: apache-kafka

How to prevent consumer commit offset when it auto-commit.
I got 1 message and i blocked it so i dont want to commit to offset it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition, you cannot prevent commits with auto-commits.